# Rails devise validate IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to validate an IP address before I login in my Admin Controller.

```
before_filter :validate_ip
```

How should I create this IP validation? I just want to write the IP addresses that have access in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is dynamic, because you can populate the array in runtime:

```
 def validate_ip
   valid = %w[127.0.0.1 10.0.0.1]
   redirect_to(login_path) unless valid.include?(request.remote_ip)
 end
```

---

The other way to restrict IPs is, to use constraints in your `routes.rb`:

```
get '/admin' => 'admin#super_secure_action', :constraints => { :ip => %w[127.0.0.1 10.0.0.1] }

# or

constraints(:ip => %w[127.0.0.1 10.0.0.1]) do
  # Every route defined in here will be restricted.
  get '/admin' => 'admin#super_secure_action'
end
```

For more information about Rails and Routes, be sure to check out: [Rails Dispatch - The Powerful New Rails Router](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing).

Comment: How secure is it? Is there any better validation ?

Comment: I would not rely only on IP filtering, you should definitely use password authentication. The combination of both systems should be secure.

Comment: Why are you rolling you own authentication when there are lots of available plugins? I suggest checking out devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Comment: if I use your dynamic approach, it will block access to every controller, right? How can I block only access to devise controllers?

Comment: @AdrianoBacha it seems that device uses `DeviseController` as base class for all its controllers, so re-opening the class and adding this lines of code should probably work.